# php messaging with redirecting

Tags: php, messaging

I am building my own content management system. And a problem that I have come across is that I handle my error messages/success messages in a non-optimal way. For example I have a page that has a form then I submit that form to the processor with a argument to redirect to the main 'listings' page with a url something like `www.example.com/projects.php?msg=success`, then after 5 secs or so the message disappears using jquery. I realize this is a far from optimal way of doing messages because if the user reloads the page the msg shows again because the `?msg=success` is still in the URL. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this (messaging with redirecting)? Keep in mind I do no want to change the structure of my CMS.

Comment: You could store the message in the `$_SESSION` variable and destroy it once it's been displayed.

Comment: What was the justification for calling it "bad form"? I'm just curious because this would have been my solution (since it will work). My philosophy is to write code that does the job. If you learn of a better way to do it later, refactor.

Comment: I agree with Matt's solution.

Comment: anyone know of any tutorials? or places where I can find info on this? found a youtube video but other than that nothing much. perhaps im not googling the right thing

Comment: this seems good btw http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/